# Magento 2.1.4 - Set default root category

Tags: category, magento-2.1.4

The first time I configured the categories, I renamed the default category. Now, I need to change the default category because it is the first category to be shown when I go to the categories menu. So **I added a new root category** but I didn't see any options to **set it as default**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make yoru root category as default category by **following below steps :**

- Logged in to your magento2 admin panel
- Click on Stores -> All stores -> it will display grid for all stores
- Now click on Your main website store listed under the store column
- You will see Root Category option over there -> Select category which you want to make it as a root

**Click on save and checked it, it  will work**

Refer below screenshot for more details :

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I was thinking. I should have put more details in my question.
By default category, I mean the category which is selected by default when you go to the **Products > Categories** menu.
Your answer help me to fix the issue. To do it, I just needed to create a new website which has the category that I want to be shown in first and set this website as default.
Thank you !