# Magento 2: Category URL for frontend

Tags: magento2, category, frontend, url

I have created a root category with name `colors` in Magento 2. I am trying to access this category by URL `http://domain.com/category/colors.html` in front end. But its not working for me. What will the URL of colors category for access product listing of this category on front end?

Comment: checked not working for me

Answer (score 2):

Please find the steps to create a category and access the category in the URL

1. Login to the admin Catalog->Inventory->Categories-> click 'Default category' and click 'Add subcategory' and add the category in the Magento. For example, if you creating a category with name 'colors' means you can access the category in the frontend like this http://domain.com/colors.html.

If you have any doubt what URL to access in the frontend. kindly go to the admin, catalog->Inventory->Categories-> select a particular category and goto search engine optimization ->Url key-> here you can find the exact name.

Comment: the path you added is no correct. `Catalog->Inventory->Categories->_ _ _` is wrong

Comment: Thanks @SathishrajRaju.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to assign new **Root Category** to your currently active store.

To do this follow below guide:

> - Login to back end. Go to Stores-> All Stores
> - Than select your store for which you want to display Root Category.
> - By default It's using **Default Root Category** Change it and select your Root Category than save.

For More details : [Magento 2.1.4 - Set default root category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165370/magento-2-1-4-set-default-root-category)

**Reindex data and Clear Cache.**

Comment: Thanks for your help, now its working for me. I have updated the root category to `colors`as per above guideline. After that I am able to access its child category only. Here is the URL of one child category of `colors` category `http://domain.com/catalog/category/view/s/brickweb-flats/id/16/`

Comment: @PankajSharma Glad to know. Could you please also mark answer as accepted so that It will help other users as well.